# How to recognize an Apriltag using a NN and with only one class

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, apriltags

Context: I have a video sequence of a camera moving around in a room with Apriltags (sort of QRcodes) on the walls.

I want to recognize those Apriltags using a Neural Network.

Problem is that I only have Apriltags images in my training set.

What would you suggest to recognize if an image belongs to the Apriltag class or not ?

For example if the image is a chessboard how can my NN reject this image ?